# How to check if url/links exist in page in Capybara?

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara, automated-tests

I've been searching for so long already but haven't found any solution.

I would like to check if a particular URL exists in the page. Rspec Capybara

for example: I'd like to check if the url http://project/guides/basics/ is in the page.

capybara has `has_link` function but only accepts an `id` or `text` as a parameter so for this example,

```
<a href='http://project/guides/basics/'>
    <div class='image-button-container'>
        <img src='/images/basic_img.png'/>
    </div>
</a>
```

how should I do the `expect()` in Rspec using Capybara? Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following two should work:

```
expect(page).to have_link('', href: 'http://project/guides/basics/')
expect(page).to have_selector("a[href='http://project/guides/basics/']")
```

I was really hoping there is a better looking way, but unfortunately, I can't find one.

Comment: Hi @ndn! been working this for days :)  thank you very much! I didnt know that first param of `have_link()` can be an empty string. I used the first one.

Answer (score 5):

Capybara API provides method like below -

```
page.should have_link("Foo")
page.should have_link("Foo", :href=>"googl.com")
page.should have_no_link("Foo", :href=>"google.com")
```

For your specific sample you can find all elements and then check if `a` is there with specific div and image. like below -

```
page.all("a[href='http://project/guides/basics/'] div img")[0]['src'].should be('/images/basic_img.png')
```

Comment: Hi @Vishnu thanks for answering. based on my example above? how would I apply your answer? thanks

Comment: Updated answer with your sample html